# Issue when Creating a Case Statement in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, if-statement

I'm having some sort of an issue with the CASE statement in the database I'm working in Microsoft Access 2007.
Right now, this is my query:

```
SELECT Email, CASE State
WHEN "NC" THEN "North Carolina"
ELSE "Not Known"
END AS "Origin"
FROM Customers
```

All of the data objects have the correct names, and I can't tell why the query won't run for the life of me. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Do you get an error message or doesn't you conversion work or...

Comment: It says "syntax error: CASE State
WHEN "NC" THEN "North Carolina"
ELSE "Not Known"
END "

Answer (score 3):

Access doesn't support `CASE`. For that example you could use [`IIF`](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3)

```
SELECT Email,
       IIF(State = "NC", "North Carolina", "Not Known") AS "Origin"
FROM   Customers
```

If that was a cut down example you probably want a table mapping State codes and names that you outer join on.

Or possibly you could use [`SWITCH`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-Function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379)

```
SELECT
   Switch(
         State = "NC", "North Carolina",
         State = "SC", "South Carolina"
         True,"Not Known"
         ) AS Origin
FROM   Customers;
```

Comment: Does the IIF statement only support an "if" and "else"? Or could I also work in multiple states for example?

Comment: @potatosoup - `IIF` is just two branches. There is a `SWITCH` function though. I've had a stab at the syntax from a quick look at the docs but can't guarantee that it will work as desired as I'm not in a position to test.

Comment: In fact, this is just a small example of what my real issue is. I have time periods such as "Quarterly, Annually, Bi-annually", etc, but I want to create a column using the DateAdd, telling me how far in advanced that "quarterly" or "yearly" would be. The DateAdd syntax I have figured out correctly, but is there a way I can create a new column based on the new date that is calculated?

Comment: @potatosoup - This requirement doesn't seem to have anything to do with `CASE`.

Comment: Just handle Null within `Switch` same as any State value which doesn't match one of the cases: `Switch(State = "NC", "North Carolina", State = "SC", "South Carolina", True, "Not Known") AS Origin`

Comment: @HansUp - That's *much* simpler. Thanks.

Comment: Another Access "feature" is that quoting an alias actually includes those quotes in the name ... which is not what most folks expect.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with something like:

```
SELECT Email, Iif(State = "NC", "North Carolina", "Not Known") AS "Origin" FROM Customers
```

Your CASE statement corresponds to MSSQL syntax which offen used as BE database for Access application. But it is not supported by Access.